# Does curl execute the PHP script on the remote server?

Tags: php, curl

This is a fairly simple question, yet I haven't been able to find a simple answer.

If I use curl on Server1 to access a PHP file on Server2, is the code in that file executed on Server2?

I have a script on a remote server that I need to be able to execute from my main server. The code should be executed on the remote server where the PHP file resides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Same as you'd enter that address to internet browser.

Comment: Adding the usual caveat "if the server is configured to run the PHP script on access of that URL." Of course the server could be configured to just return the contents of that script. But the latter part of your answer is the key.